# How to pass the id value of an url with axios and javascript for a single element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm showing the data parameters (name, height, mass...) for a character using the swapi (https://swapi.co/), AXIOS and VUE.

I already have the url for a character (i.e http://localhost:8081/person/1) and I want it to match with the swapi API (https://swapi.co/api/people/1/), but I don't know where is my error

I'm using Axios and Vue, I've made a service for the Axios get request and the method to get the information in my vue file.

The code for my "people.service.js" service is this:

```
import axios from "axios";

const PeopleService = {};

// PeoplesService.getPeoples = async () => {}; - Para sacar el listado de planetas con un v-for

PeopleService.getPeople = async id => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(`people/${id}`);

    // For getting the species

    const specieRoute = result.data.species[0].split("/");
    const idSpecie = specieRoute[specieRoute.length - 2];
    const especie = await axios.get(`species/${idSpecie}`);

    // For getting the planets

    const planetRoute = result.data.homeworld.split("/");
    const idPlanet = planetRoute[planetRoute.length - 2];
    const planeta = await axios.get(`planets/${idPlanet}`);

    // console logs to show results

    console.log(result.data);
    console.log(idSpecie);
    console.log(especie.data);
    console.log(planeta.data);

    // data information

    const people = {
      nombre: result.data.name,
      altura: result.data.height,
      peso: result.data.mass,
      genero: result.data.gender,
      piel: result.data.skin_color,
      especie: especie.data.name, // Lo saco del servicio de especies
      planeta: planeta.data.name // Lo saco del servicio de planetas
    };

    return people;
  } catch (error) {
    const errorStatus = error.response.status;
    let errorMessage = "";

    if (errorStatus === 404) {
      errorMessage = "No se encontró al personaje";
    } else {
      errorMessage = "Ocurrió un error";
    }

    throw new Error(errorMessage);
  }
};

export default PeopleService;
```

And my vue file is:

```
<template>
  <div>

    The id is {{ $route.params.id }}, and the name is {{ people.nombre }}

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PeopleService from "@/services/people.service";

export default {
  async create() {
    this.userId = this.$route.params.id;
    this.getUser();
  },

  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      userId: this.$route.params.id
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getUser() {
      try {
        this.loading = true;
        this.people = null;
        this.error = null;
        this.people = await PeopleService.getPeople(this.userId);
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.message;
      } finally {
        this.userId = null;
        this.loading = false;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

I expect the result to be the name of the character, but i get **`"[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined"`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating a second answer in order to outline how you could do this using `vue-router`, since you were asking about it.

*Disclaimer:* this isn't the 'cleanest' code - this pseudo code is designed to loosely illustrate your objective.

Hope this helps!

---

[CodePen mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/oOeQXm?editors=1010)

---

```js
const PeopleService = {};
PeopleService.getPeople = async id => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${id}`);
    const specieRoute = result.data.species[0].split("/");
    const idSpecie = specieRoute[specieRoute.length - 2];
    const especie = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/species/${idSpecie}`);
    const planetRoute = result.data.homeworld.split("/");
    const idPlanet = planetRoute[planetRoute.length - 2];
    const planeta = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/planets/${idPlanet}`);
    const people = {
      nombre: result.data.name,
      altura: result.data.height,
      peso: result.data.mass,
      genero: result.data.gender,
      piel: result.data.skin_color,
      especie: especie.data.name, // Lo saco del servicio de especies
      planeta: planeta.data.name // Lo saco del servicio de planetas
    };
    return people;
  } catch (error) {
    const errorStatus = error.response.status;
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (errorStatus === 404) {
      errorMessage = "No se encontró al personaje";
    } else {
      errorMessage = "Ocurrió un error";
    }
    throw new Error(errorMessage);
  }
};

const peopleComponent = {
  name: 'people',
  template: "#peopleComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      userId: null,
      peopleArray: [],
      peopleObject: null,
      error: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.userId = this.$route.params.id;
    this.getUser();
  },
  methods: {
    async getUser() {
      try {
        let person = await PeopleService.getPeople(this.userId);
        this.peopleArray.push(person); // add to array
        this.peopleObject = person; // assign to object
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.message;
      }
    }
  }
};

const homeComponent = {
  name: 'home',
  template: "#homeComponent",
}

const routes = [
    { path: '', name: 'home', component: homeComponent },
    { path: '/people/:id', name: 'people', component: peopleComponent },
]

const router = new VueRouter({ routes });

new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

```css
.nav-links {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.4/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="homeComponent">
  <div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <div>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'people', params: { id: 1 } }">Person 1</router-link>
        <br/>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'people', params: { id: 2 } }">Person 2</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/><br/>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="peopleComponent">
  <div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <h2>People</h2>
      <div>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">Home</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/><br/>
    <h3>People as ARRAY</h3>
    <div v-if="peopleArray.length > 0">
      <div v-for="(p, index) in peopleArray" :key="index">
        <div><b>nombre:</b> {{ p.nombre }}</div>
        <div><b>altura:</b> {{ p.altura }}</div>
        <div><b>peso:</b> {{ p.peso }}</div>
        <div><b>genero:</b> {{ p.genero }}</div>
        <div><b>piel:</b> {{ p.piel }}</div>
        <div><b>especie:</b> {{ p.especie }}</div>
        <div><b>planeta:</b> {{ p.planeta }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <i>Loading People...</i>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <hr/> --- OR ---
    <hr/><br/>
    <h3>People as OBJECT</h3>
    <div v-if="peopleObject != null">
      <div v-for="(p, index) in peopleObject" :key="index">
        {{ p }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <i>Loading People...</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Great! this is exactly what I was looking for, my problem was with the userId in mounted!

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** it doesn't appear you have a `data.people` property set up before assigning a value to it.. Can you try to add a `people` property under data and try again?

```
...
data() {
  return {
    ...
    people: null,
    ...
  }
}
...
```

---

First and foremost, it is not very clear how you are actually sending requests to `swapi`.. how are you doing this?

I wrote a modified version of what you're trying to accomplish using your code, but with the `swapi` URL.. if you change your code to use the `swapi` URL instead of `localhost`, does it work?

---

[CodePen mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/oOePyZ?editors=1010)

*Code snippet is also available below*

*Edit:* [CodePen with routing example](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/oOeQXm?editors=1010) - detailed secondary answer has also been posted..

---

*If you're proxying requests locally*

What does your server side configuration look like? Are you using `node` or something else? How are you **actually** sending API requests to `swapi`?

---

*If you're using a local database*

Does your local database have any data in it? You may need to set up a service that pulls down data from the `swapi` API and saves it to your local database, before trying to query your local database for data.

---

I am also not using any routing, so there could be an issue with your routes? At any rate, I hope this helps:

```js
/**
 * People service
 */
const PeopleService = {};
PeopleService.getPeople = async id => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${id}`);
    const specieRoute = result.data.species[0].split("/");
    const idSpecie = specieRoute[specieRoute.length - 2];
    const especie = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/species/${idSpecie}`);
    const planetRoute = result.data.homeworld.split("/");
    const idPlanet = planetRoute[planetRoute.length - 2];
    const planeta = await axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/planets/${idPlanet}`);
    const people = {
      nombre: result.data.name,
      altura: result.data.height,
      peso: result.data.mass,
      genero: result.data.gender,
      piel: result.data.skin_color,
      especie: especie.data.name,
      planeta: planeta.data.name
    };
    return people;
  } catch (error) {
    const errorStatus = error.response.status;
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (errorStatus === 404) {
      errorMessage = "No se encontró al personaje";
    } else {
      errorMessage = "Ocurrió un error";
    }
    throw new Error(errorMessage);
  }
};

/** 
 * Vue app
 */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    userId: 1,
    peopleArray: [],
    peopleObject: null,
    error: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUser();
  },
  methods: {
    async getUser() {
      try {
        let person = await PeopleService.getPeople(this.userId);
        this.peopleArray.push(person); // add to array
        this.peopleObject = person; // assign to object
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.message;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>People as ARRAY</h3>
  <div v-if="peopleArray.length > 0">
    <div v-for="(p, index) in peopleArray" :key="index">
      <div><b>nombre:</b> {{ p.nombre }}</div>
      <div><b>altura:</b> {{ p.altura }}</div>
      <div><b>peso:</b> {{ p.peso }}</div>
      <div><b>genero:</b> {{ p.genero }}</div>
      <div><b>piel:</b> {{ p.piel }}</div>
      <div><b>especie:</b> {{ p.especie }}</div>
      <div><b>planeta:</b> {{ p.planeta }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <i>Loading People...</i>
  </div>
  <br/><hr/> --- OR --- <hr/><br/>
  <h3>People as OBJECT</h3>
  <div v-if="peopleObject != null">
    <div v-for="(p, index) in peopleObject" :key="index">
      {{ p }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <i>Loading People...</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! the main problem now is with the userID, I want it to match with my url, for example, if localhost/person/5, I need the userID=5.

I've used userID: this.$router.params.id, but does nothing.

Comment: What worked? Adding the `people` property under data? It's hard to tell what's going wrong with your routes without seeing a router config. Can you update your question with your router config?

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for the vue file is:

```
<template>
<div>
  <h3>Modo array</h3>
  <div v-if="peopleArray.length > 0"> // Detecta que el id es mayor que 0
    <div v-for="(p, index) in peopleArray" :key="index">
      <div><b>nombre:</b> {{ p.nombre }}</div>
      <div><b>altura:</b> {{ p.altura }}</div>
      <div><b>peso:</b> {{ p.peso }}</div>
      <div><b>genero:</b> {{ p.genero }}</div>
      <div><b>piel:</b> {{ p.piel }}</div>
      <div><b>especie:</b> {{ p.especie }}</div>
      <div><b>planeta:</b> {{ p.planeta }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <i>Loading People...</i>
  </div>
  <br/><hr/> --- <hr/><br/>
  <h3>Modo objeto</h3>
  <div v-if="peopleObject != null">
    <div v-for="(p, index) in peopleObject" :key="index">
      {{ p }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <i>Loading People...</i>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PeopleService from "@/services/people.service";

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      userId: null,
      loading: false,
      peopleArray: [], // Para obtener los valores como array
      peopleObject: null, // Para que los valores que devuelva sean como array o como objeto
      error: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.userId = this.$route.params.id; // el userId corresponde con el último número de la url
    this.getUser();  
    },
  methods: {
    async getUser() {
      try {
        this.loading = true;
        this.people = null;
        this.error = null;
        let person = await PeopleService.getPeople(this.userId); // Hace la petición sobre el userID
        this.peopleArray.push(person); // Añadir al array
        this.peopleObject = person; // Asignar a objeto
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.message;
      } finally {
        this.userId = null;
        this.loading = false;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```